# C++: How to force libc declarations into std::?

Tags: c++, namespaces, libc, libstdc++

So, I find myself in the need of libc in my C++ program. However, I do not like the idea of sprinkling it all over the global namespace. Ideally, I'd like to force the entirety of libc into the `std::` namespace so I'd have to do `std::memcpy` rather than `memcpy`.

Is this possible? And how? I'm willing to use compiler-specific macros if needed (I target only MS VC++ 10.0 and GCC 4.6).

Edit: I do literally mean 'force the declarations into std' - so that they are uncallable without the std:: prefix. Also, I am including `cstdio`, not `stdio.h`.

Thanks!

Comment: *"I do literally mean 'force the declarations into std' - so that they are uncallable without the std:: prefix."* The programmer who comes after you may not appreciate this.

Comment: It's an open source project with established coding conventions. I could write a thesis on why contributors should not be altering code style, but this isn't the place...

Comment: In theory, when you include the `<cname>` headers, all the non-macro entities are only supposed to be included in `std` and not in the global namespace.  In practice, most implementations don't do that, and the next C++ standard, C++0x, has changed the rules to allow the `<cname>` headers to put names into the global namespace as well.

Comment: Seems to me that they're making it worse... But no matter, it is what it is.

Comment: I agree that it's worse, but it's kind of useless to impose rules that no one follows :-|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this, unless it's already done.

The namespace `std` is reserved to the Standard Library, it is forbidden to add new members to this namespace. Therefore, if the C-headers are not already embedded within `std`, then you have no choice but to accept it.

On the other hand, you can perfectly create a new namespace, `cstd`, and bring the symbols from the global namespace in it with `using` directives... but it won't make them *disappear* from the global namespace.

Answer (score 1):

> I do literally mean 'force the declarations into std' - so that they are uncallable without the std:: prefix.

You can't do this if your implementation exposes the names in the global namespace.  You can use the <cXXX> headers and then use std:: yourself.

This is, perhaps, unfortunate, but it is a consequence of C compatibility, since C does not understand namespaces.  C++ has traditionally maintained many kludges and sacrifices for C compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Make wrapper includes

```
//stdlib.hpp
namespace std
{
#include <stdlib.h> //edit: changed from cstdlib to stdlib.h
}
```

If the linker hates this try just declaring the functions you want:

```
namespace std{ extern "C" {

int memcpy( void *out, const void *in);
} }
```

Comment: They are already in the `std` namespace. Also, the MS VC++ headers add `using std::<function>` for every single libc function, so this won't help. Not sure if GCC does the same.

Comment: The using won't do crap because it's wrapped in another std namespace. What happens is namespace std{ namespace std{ ...} using std::foo }. The linker probably wouldn't like it, except it will be able to find the symbol `std::memcpy` in the crt libs. There may be an issue if It forces itself to look for `std::std::memcpy`

Comment: Point taken. This works excellently on MS VC++, however, not on GCC 4.1.2: http://paste2.org/p/1230554

Comment: This is very likely to break or otherwise simply do the wrong thing.

Comment: Ok. Try using `#include <stdio.h>` instead of `cstdio`. The _lib_.h files do not have the namespace stuff in them. It works in gcc 4.2.1

Comment: The edit which wraps <stdlib.h> in namespace std is also very likely to break or otherwise simply do the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

The reason some (most?) C++ compilers have the C functions in the global namespace, is simply that they have to use the existing operating system functions. For example, the file functions might not be a separate C library, but the file handling of the OS.