# Is there a way to disable global identifiers in C headers?

Tags: c++, gcc, namespaces

In GCC I'm allowed to do this:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
  printf("foo");
  std::printf("bar"); // "correct" way
}
```

Is there a way I can get a error/warning if I attempt the first?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be in version 4.4 at least. Did you check your version?

Comment: Unless the implementation did it already, no. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909420/c-how-to-force-libc-declarations-into-std

Comment: Note that the standard requires that the implementation declares them inside the `std` namespace, but does not forbid implementations from also declaring it in the global namespace.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's how `cstdio` is meant to work. To do it the way you want would be against the standard.

It's rather hard to argue that `std::printf` is *correct* in C++. Using `std::cout` is the *correct* way to do this.

**Update** As others point out, the standard only mandates that the functions are declared in the std namespace. Implementations are permitted to define them additionally in the global namespace.

Comment: It's not hard for Google - http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Streams (Also, I thought that `stdio.h` was supposed to expose only `printf` (and so on) and that `cstdio` was supposed to expose only `std::printf` (and so on) - essentially that `cstdio` looks like `namespace std {` / `#include <stdio.h>` / `};` (obviously it'll end up being more complicated than that, but you get the idea).

Comment: @ChrisLutz `cstdio` includes `stdio.h` **outside** the `namespace std` block. So this is indeed how cstdio is meant to work.

Comment: I've never gone to the standard to check, but I was always under the impression otherwise. The more you know...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: [headers]: "[...] the contents of each header cname shall be the same as that of the corresponding header name.h [...]. In the C++ standard library, however, the declarations (except for names which are defined as macros in C) are within namespace scope (3.3.6) of the namespace std. It is unspecified whether these names are first declared within the global namespace scope and are then injected into namespace std by explicit using-declarations (7.3.3)."

Comment: @ybungalobill The end result is the same though

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The end result is unspecified, so it can't be always the same. But it definitely wouldn't be "against the standard" if the behavior the OP wants had been implemented.

Comment: @ybungalobill That seems odd. Wouldn't that make it rather hard to write portable code?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: As hard as always. Just pick the one way you like: include stdio.h and use the global scope or include cstdio and use the std namespace.

Comment: 100% with ybungalobill: The standard allows the implementation to just include `stdio.h` and bring the symbols into the `std` namespace, but does not mandate it. It is commonly used due to the fact that most C++ compilers are also C compilers, and this allows for a single declaration/definition of the functions in both `stdio.h` and `cstdio`. But it could be the other way around, with a compiler defining them in C++ in the `std` namespace in `cstdio` and then offering a light C wrapper in the global namespace...

Comment: A significant advantage of `ostream` vs `printf` is the ability to define your own `operator << (ostream&, yourtype)` to extend it. AFAIK, `printf` can't be easily extended (except as a GNU Libc extension http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Customizing-Printf.html)

Answer (score 0):

`printf` is an `extern "C"` function from `<stdio.h>` (a standard C header file)  which is included from `<cstdio>` but `std::printf` is a C++ thing. And C++ output is usually better done to `std::cout` using the `std::ostream` standard C++ class. I don't know of a way to get warning when using `<stdio.h>` functions, but if that really matters to you, you might consider customizing your GCC compiler with e.g. a [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension. Customizing GCC may take a week or more of efforts for someone who never did it before (because you need to understand some of GCC internal representations).

Comment: Saying `std::ostream > std::printf` is debatable - see http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Streams

Comment: Working on standard C++ or C libraries is quite hard, and the result won't be standard anymore.

Comment: @ChrisLutz: the Google Style Guide is braindead, it preaches all that Modern C++ abhors. That said, I agree it's debatable, the streams don't allow as much formatting as printf does.

Answer (score 0):

As you have written the program NO you cannot get a warning / error because cstdio is supposed to expose the std::printf out so that it can be used WITHOUT the namespace qualifier.  It has `using` directives defined specifically to allow the use of std:: namespace functions without generating the error.

Specifically `cstdio` contains:

```
namespace std
{
  using ::FILE;
  using ::fpos_t;

  using ::clearerr;
  using ::fclose;
 ...
}
```

Note that this is part of the standard... cstdio is SUPPOSED to act this way.

Comment: This is misleading: `cstdio` is required to declare the symbols in the `std` namespace, and the standard does not forbid the implementation from declaring them elsewhere (i.e. global namespace), but that is quite different from *cstdio is supposed to expose the std::printf out so that it can be used WITHOUT namespace*. It is allowed to do so, it is **not** supposed to do it.